# I am not able to place a picture in React Native

Tags: javascript, image, react-native, splash-screen

I am trying to make an app in react native and am starting to at least place an image as the screen when you click on the app.

The problem is that the app is unable to find the image or the javascript file that I call. I tried to change the location of the files and it seems to not be doing anything.

Here is the code for the Start Screen file

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Image} from 'react-native';

const StartScreen = () => (
    <Image source = {require('./src/assets/images/StartScreen.png')} />
)

export default StartScreen
```

Here is the code for the App.js file

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import StartScreen from './src/screens/StartScreen'

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
         <StartScreen />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I should be getting the picture but am instead getting told that the picture or the file do not exist. The App.js file is in the top level of the folder, while the picture and StartScreen.js are in a src folder.

Comment: make sure the image path is correct. Is your image folder outside src?

Comment: No, I have placed the image folder in an assets folder in the src folder

Comment: I presume the path is wrong.

Comment: Thank you, I think that this is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your problem lies in your folder structure & the path you're using to require your image.

From what I can gather, your StartScreen.js file is in a `screens` folder (which is in `src`), and your image is in an `assets` folder (which is also in `src`).

So in your `StartScreen` component your relative path for your image is wrong. Take a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp) for an explanation of how relative paths work.

Try the below:

`<Image source = {require('../assets/images/StartScreen.png')} />`